# How to SSH into docker container by a non-root user of that container?

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, openssh

I am using OpenSSH her. I can easily ssh using `root@serverIP -p portNumber`, but whenever I try to ssh via a docker container user like `user@@serverIP -p portNumber` it gives me permission denied.

Moreover, I have also seen the ssh service is not starting when I opt to use my user to start the container instead of the root. Please help me what am I missing here?

I am giving my dockerfile below:

P.S: I know that instead of ssh I can just use `docker exec` but I have a strict condition to use ssh here. Thank you.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Mahiuddin Al Kamal <mahiuddin_al.kamal@mailbox.tu-dresden.de>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN useradd -rm -d /home/ubuntu -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1000 ubuntu

RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server build-essential wget make python gcc sshpass vim-tiny

RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN wget -O mcperf.tar.gz https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/twemperf/mcperf-0.1.1.tar.gz
RUN mkdir mcperf && tar -xvf mcperf.tar.gz --strip-components=1  -C ./mcperf/
RUN cd /mcperf && ./configure && make && make install

RUN wget -O dude.tar.gz https://bitbucket.org/db7/dude/get/v3.1.tar.gz && mkdir dude && tar -xvf dude.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C ./dude/
RUN cd /dude && python setup.py install

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

RUN sed -i 's/22/10023/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN apt-get -y install r-base

RUN echo 'screencast' > sshpass.txt && chmod 777 sshpass.txt

#sshpass -p screencast ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@172.19.0.2
#sshpass -f sshpass.txt ssh root@172.19.0.2 


RUN mkdir /home/ubuntu/a2p08

COPY Benchmark.py /home/ubuntu/a2p08/
COPY Dudefile /home/ubuntu/a2p08/
COPY graphs.R /home/ubuntu/a2p08/
COPY run.sh /home/ubuntu/a2p08/

WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/a2p08/

RUN chmod 777 *

USER ubuntu

EXPOSE 10023

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect sshd service to be run with "root", so try to remove

```
USER ubuntu
```

Also, to set user "ubuntu" password,

```
RUN echo 'ubuntu:ubuntu' | chpasswd
```

Then you should be able to ssh with user "ubuntu"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`ssh docker@<docker machine ip>`. i.e. `ssh docker@192.168.99.100`

`password: tcuser`